# Download images from html and keep the folder structure

Tags: php, regex, image

I need to have download over 100.000 pictures. The Pictures have : .png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif format.
I have the approval to use those pictures. they have provide me an XML file with all the url`s

The url have the structure

otherdomain/productimages/code/imagename.jpg/.png/.gif

I have all the codes in an php array called `$codes[]`
I have also the full path of the all images on an array `$images[]`

I need to have all those pictures downloaded and keep the same structure

mydomain/productimages/code/imagename.jpg/.png/.gif

What i have so far due my reasearch over internet is :

Looping over all the pages ( each hotel code )

```
   $i = 1;
   $r = 100000;

while ($i < $r) {
    $html = get_data('http://otherdomain.com/productimages/'.$codes[$i].'/');
    getImages($html);
    $codes[$i++];
}

    function getImages($html) {
        $matches = array();
        $regex = '~http://otherdomain.com/productimages/(.*?)\.jpg~i';
        preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches);
        foreach ($matches[1] as $img) {
            saveImg($img);
        }
    }

    function saveImg($name) {
        $url = 'http://otherdomain.com/productimages/'.$name.'.jpg';
        $data = get_data($url);
        file_put_contents('photos/'.$name.'.jpg', $data);
    }
```

Could you help me to get this working as the script doesnt work at all

Comment: Try using file_get_contents instead of get_data

Comment: still no effect @flyingeagle413

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I may suggest you the easier and faster approach to the task.
Write a complete URLs to the list.txt
execute wget -x -i list.txt command which will download all the images and put them in appropriate directories according to the site structure.

Comment: it works very fine, does it happend to know if i can set the wget to download all the files to a certain location eg HTTP root folder ?

Answer (score 0):

In response to

> it works very fine, does it happend to know if i can set the wget to download all the files to a certain location eg HTTP root folder ?

The wget downloads to the folder it is being run, so you could just cd to the folder and do the wget in there.

Also, to complement @Hlorofos answer, you can use -nH, so the folder structure doesn't include the host URL.